# Docker network with unique name

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I'm using Docker user-defined bridge network and network-scoped aliases to isolate my tests.

It is possible that on CI server more then one version of the same test are run in parallel. If I would use hard-coded network name it may interfere.

To avoid this I generate unique network name (by uuidgen) and use it during test.

```
TEST_IMAGE_ID="$(docker build -q .)"

UNIQUE_NETWORK_NAME="$(docker run --rm $TEST_IMAGE_ID uuidgen)"

docker network create --driver bridge "$UNIQUE_NETWORK_NAME"

CONT_B_ID="$(docker run -d --rm  --network=$UNIQUE_NETWORK_NAME --network-alias=proxy -v ${WORKSPACE}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx:alpine)"
```

My questions:

1. What is the best practice here?
2. Why Docker cannot create a user-defined network without specifying its name, like it does for images and containers?

Comment: I guess you need to specify names for the network because if you require custom networks to control access you would want to be particular when specifying them in compose, etc. But I can see your need for auto generated names. The way you are doing it seems fine though. I wonder if Docker would support this, you could open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: I have created a feature request https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/153

Comment: Thumbs upped it as it's a nice idea, I would use this myself in the CI pipelines.